# Dealing with a very large TSP-esque problem (80,000+ items)

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, traveling-salesman

The problem is as follows:

---

An input text file will contain N lines each representing a book. Each book will have G genres associated with it with 1<=G<=100.

You want to order those books in terms of interest factor. Several books that are too similar are boring while books that are too different can cause visitors  to be confused. Thus the score for each pair of books is MIN(genres unique to book i,genres unique to book i+1, genres common between books).

There are several files with one having 80,000 books

---

I am new to optimisation (this is my first time working on a problem like this), and the first thing I thought of was to simply create a NxN 2-d array with the scores from and to each book (node) and at each step choose the best possible book to add to the "path".

However, due to the size of the problem, I was unable to create such a large array. So instead, I broke the problem into 8 sections of 10,000 books each and was able to go on with that idea. Unfortunately, the time it takes to finish running is quite great (more than an hour). Although the score was quite decent.

I tried Simulated Annealing where you would randomly switch two books. I used temperature of 100,000 and cooling rate of 0.0005. That also took a long time and gave a worse score than the other approach.

I was wondering if there is a way to improve those approaches (in terms of time taken) or if there was a better approach/algorithm for solving this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "order those books in terms of interest factor." "Interest factor" sounds like a property of one book, not a pair, but your "score" is based on pairs. Since you said this is TSP-esque, do you mean something like, "find a sequence of books so the sum of all the scores(i,i+1) is minimized, where score(i,i+1) is the score between book i and the next consecutive book on the sequence"?

Comment: In any case, if your problem is only that you can't store an 80,000 x 80,000 array, what if you just write a function that calculates score(i,j) as needed, rather than pre-computing them all?